# console.logging data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am still trying to comprehend `Mongoose/Mongo`

Now in terminal When I do something like this in terminal

```
use library 
show collections 
db.authors.find().pretty()
```

I get something like this in logged

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc8704f3a9828d5513505a2"),
    "name" : "Aman",
    "age" : "21",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc870553a9828d5513505a3"),
    "name" : "Rohit",
    "age" : "20",
    "__v" : 0
}


{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bc8704f3a9828d5513505a7"),
        "name" : "Aman",
        "age" : "21",
        "__v" : 0
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bc870553a9828d5513505a5"),
        "name" : "Rohit",
        "age" : "20",
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Now, I want to have same data in my NodeJs i.e say, I want to find wherever the name is Rohit and want to link it with with some other db or schema.

how can I get the same output which I just obtained by running the above given command in terminal window of mongo in NodeJS

Obviously doing something like this `console.log(db.authors.find())` won't work, so how can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I usually write my database queries.

First create a schema that your model will follow. Don't worry this schema is flexible and you can change it at any time without affecting old data.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var authorSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    default: 20
  }
});
```

Next create a model from your schema.

```
var authorModel = mongoose.model('authorModel', authorSchema);
```

Lastly query your model and get the value you need

```
authorModel.find(
        {
          name: 'Rohit'
        },
        function (err, result) {
          console.log(result)
         });
```

I put my schema and controller on separate files. How you organise your code structure is up to you.

I pretty much followed [this blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) when I first learnt to build APIs on NodeJS. You might find this useful as well!